# Java - use void return type to allow customer to gain admission into event

Tags: java, constructor

I'm trying to make a method that allows a customer to gain admission into an event. As a requirement, the payAdmission() method should have a void return type. My method should also be one line long, making use of the computeFee() and spend() methods that are already written. I don't quite understand how I'm supposed to determine how a customer is supposed to pay admission when the return type is just void and I'm unable to subtract any values or return anything?

Code for Customer Class:

```
public class Customer {
    String name;
    int age;
    float money;

    public Customer(String initName){
        name = initName;
    }

    public Customer(String initName, int initAge){
        name = initName;
        age = initAge;
    }

    public Customer(String initName, int initAge, float initMoney){
        name = initName;
        age = initAge;
        money = initMoney;  
    }

    public Customer(){
    }

    public float computeFee(){
        if(age >= 18 && age <65){
            return 12.75f;
        }
        if(age >= 65){
            return 0.5f;
        }
        if(age >= 4 && age <= 17){
            return 8.50f;
        }
        return 0.0f;
    }

    public boolean spend(float amount){
        if(amount <= money){
            money -= amount;
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }

    public boolean hasMoreMoneyThan(Customer c){
        if(this.money > c.money){
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public void payAdmission(){
      float comF = computeFee();
      float spe = spend();
      float moneyLeft -= (comF + spe);
    }
}
```

Code for CustomerAdmissionTestProgram:

```
public class CustomerAdmissionTestProgram {
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    Customer c1, c2, c3, c4;
    c1 = new Customer("Bob", 17, 100);
    c2 = new Customer("Dottie", 3, 10);
    c3 = new Customer("Jane", 24, 40);
    c4 = new Customer("Sam", 72, 5);
    System.out.println("Here is the money before going into the circus:");
    System.out.println(" Bob has $" + c1.money);
    System.out.println(" Dottie has $" + c2.money);
    System.out.println(" Jane has $" + c3.money);
    System.out.println(" Sam has $" + c4.money);
    // Simulate people going into the circus

    c1.payAdmission();
    c2.payAdmission();
    c3.payAdmission();
    c4.payAdmission();

    System.out.println("Here is the money after going into the circus:");
    System.out.println(" Bob has $" + c1.money);
    System.out.println(" Dottie has $" + c2.money);
    System.out.println(" Jane has $" + c3.money);
    System.out.println(" Sam has $" + c4.money);


 }
}
```

Comment: Use and update member variables instead of working with local variables and check what type a method returns, a boolean is not a float.

Comment: `float spe = spend();` is not correct - it returns a boolean.  You should not continue if it returns false

Comment: the code you posted now won't compile. you have a closing bracket too much after the hasMoreMoneyThan method

Comment: Why do you want to calculate the remaining money in the `payAdmission()` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look carefully at what the `spend` and `computeFee` methods do. `spend` takes in an amount and subtracts it from the money (if the person has enough money to spend, of course). The `computeFee` method calculates and returns the fee.

So what should `payAdmission` do? It naturally follows that it should spend the fee. How do you get the fee? By calling `computeFee`. How do you spend it? By calling `spend`.

So your method should be implemented like this:

```
spend(computeFee());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String... args) {
    List<Customer> customers = Arrays.asList(
            new Customer("Bob", 17, 100),
            new Customer("Dottie", 3, 10),
            new Customer("Jane", 24, 40),
            new Customer("Sam", 72, 5));

    System.out.println("Here is the money before going into the circus:");
    customers.forEach(customer -> System.out.format(" %s has $%.2f\n", customer.name, customer.money));

    customers.forEach(Customer::payAdmission);

    System.out.println("Here is the money after going into the circus:");
    customers.forEach(customer -> System.out.format(" %s has $%.2f\n", customer.name, customer.money));
}

public static class Customer {

    private final String name;
    private final int age;
    private double money;

    public Customer(String name) {
        this(name, 0);
    }

    public Customer(String name, int age) {
        this(name, age, 0);
    }

    public Customer(String name, int age, double money) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = Math.max(0, age);
        this.money = Math.max(0, money);
    }

    public double computeFee() {
        if (age >= 65)
            return 0.5;
        if (age >= 18)
            return 12.75;
        if (age >= 4)
            return 8.50;
        return 0;
    }

    public boolean spend(double amount) {
        amount = Math.max(0, amount);

        if (Double.compare(amount, money) > 0)
            return false;

        money -= amount;
        return true;
    }

    public boolean hasMoreMoneyThan(Customer customer) {
        return Double.compare(money, customer.money) > 0;
    }

    public void payAdmission() {
        if (!spend(computeFee()))
            throw new RuntimeException();
    }
}
```